# Make FRX report file from PDF file

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, converters, fastreport

I have pdf with fillable fields. How can I guys convert it automatically to FRX file? If it's not able to fully convert it to FRX natively, I can arrange all fillable areas in FRX manually. I just need PDF layout in this case. Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: No, it is for Fast Report reporting system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast Report does not import PDF. You'll have to do manually in the report designer.

Comment: So I should make a new report using same content as in PDF "by hands"? No any automation?